# mysql join not working giving error

Tags: mysql, database

values table

```
id  name    attributes_id
1   black   3 [->]
2   red     3 [->]
3   blue    3 [->]
5   tortorise   3 [->]
6   oakley  1 [->]
9   green   3 [->]
10  native  1 [->]
```

product_values table

```
values_id   products_id
1 [->]  5 [->]
2 [->]  10 [->]
```

sql

```
SELECT values.name, product_values.products_id  FROM `product_values`  inner 
join values ON product_values.values_id=values.id;
```

error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values on 
product_values.values_id=values.id' at line 1
```

thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably put some quotes around the `values` table reference. It's a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html)

```
SELECT
    `values`.name,
    product_values.products_id 
FROM
    product_values
    INNER JOIN `values` ON product_values.values_id = `values`.id;
```

Comment: I feel silly now i will change the name of the table now.  I did not think it would let me name a table a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, `VALUES` is a reserved keyword of mysql. see here: [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). In order to avoid getting syntax error, the keyword or column name should be escape using this symbol called backtick. Example,

```
SELECT values.name, product_values.products_id  
FROM   `product_values`  
        inner join `values` ON product_values.values_id = `values`.id;
```